# How to perform basic http authentication to communicate with protected REST api using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, rest, rally

I am trying to access rally's web api through AngularJS web application, rally API supports basic http authentication. I justed wanted to know how is it achieved through angularJS ?

Comment: I found a proper solution for it myself. In the config block of module just add following line of code: $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + base64Provider.encode(username + ':' + password);      where username and password are the login credentials for the rally api and base64Provider.encode is used to base64encode username and password combination.

Comment: The solution you found is proper ,but there is one problem with it ,its sets the same header for all the http calls,if at any point for any service you want to have a different header for ex "bearer" then it will be a bottleneck.